# Navigation Architecture Component пересоздание фрагмента

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view, navigationcontroller, navigation

При использование Navigation Architecture Component при переходе на фрагмент в честности с использованием Navigation UI, происходит пересоздание фрагмента, и его перезагрузка, что не совсем нравиться поскольку при использование того-же BottomNavigationView фрагментам приходиться всегда загружать данные, и ViewModel в данном случае не помогает поскольку разрушается сам фрагмент. Раньше при использование FragmentManager помогала просто использование навигации за счет show и hide фрагмента. Как это можно решить сейчас ?

Пример навигации:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.secondActivity);
```

Пример того что сейчас происходит: https://youtu.be/WZN6e5YQuW0

Comment: В любом случае если не использовать FragmentManager, или другой механизм сохранения фрагментов (например setRetainInstance(true)), фрагмент пересоздаётся. Это нормальный механизм.

Comment: @virex-84, касаемо поведения согласен, но как тогда быть.  Сохранением данных? Постоянно их кэшировать? Или делать кастомный стэк ?